# Как заставить cmake собирать под платформу x64?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Есть clion и он использует cmake. Что нужно добавить в файл CMakeList чтобы компилировать под x64

Comment: `cmake` ничего не компилирует, он генерирует проектные файлы для того, что ему указано. Соответственно, нужно указать 64-х битный проект-вывод для `cmake` через ключ `-G`.

Comment: А для CLion нужно в настройках указать компилятор, который он будет использовать. Если это Windows, то нужно указать MinGW64, тогда для cmake ничего менять не нужно будет.